# How to change the text attribute of widget during run-time, android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I'm trying to create the layout dynamically based on my data model. But I have some problem doing that. The xml file I have is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="#f9f9ff">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is named as `dynamic.xml`. And I'm trying to *inflate* this layout at run-time. For that I'm doing:

```
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.vertical_container); 

    //getting the TextView and EditText view.         
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic,null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //trying to change the attributes. but #fails!
    textView.setText("Setting the text from code");
    textView.setId(3);

    //setting to the view
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.dynamic, null);
    parent.addView(view);
```

but this doesn't seems to be working! The line :

```
textView.setText("Setting the text from code");
```

doesn't work. I can see only the empty text in my emulator but not the text `Setting the text from code`. Not sure where I'm making the mistake. The changes that I made in my code are not seen in my emulator.

I can see only the `dynamic` xml layout rendered with its attributes specified!

Not sure where I'm making the mistake. Is it possible to achieve what I'm doing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you didn't show the whole code - edit the post to include the whole block, including the code that's adding the `currentView` to the view tree. how do you check that it doesn't have text? try calling `getText()` after `setText()` - does it return a correct value or `""`?

Comment: @andr: I meant when I look into my emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are setting wrong view for getting result .No need of twice inflation of layout

```
//getting the TextView and EditText view.         
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic,null);
TextView textView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

//trying to change the attributes. but #fails!
textView.setText("Setting the text from code");
textView.setId(3);

//Now you had customize your Textview .Now just add this customize view to your view
//setting to the view
parent.addView(currentView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently adding the

`view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.dynamic, null);`
to
`parent.addView(view);`

But you use `textView.setText("Setting the text from code");`
from this 
`View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic,null);`

You are not adding the currentView to the `parent`

Try this `parent.addView(currentView);`